# Need help identifying science fiction story with ex-Navy rebel and a "plague" that only affects women

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a science fiction short story. Here are the details I can remember:

Main character was former Space Navy who had been forced out for disobeying orders. Then he gets call from his fiancee (who is daughter of his former CO, the "brass hat" who got him discharged). The planet she's now on is being ravaged by a plague that only seems to affect women. The main character investigates and finds that the "plague" is actually alien life forms brought back by a science expedition that had been forced to return prematurely by bureaucratic demands.

Comment: Short story or novel? From about how long ago? Did you really mean to say that the main character's fiancee  is the "brass hat" who got him discharged? Or was her father the "brass hat" and was "&" a typo for "who"?

Comment: User14111: the fiancee's father was the brass hat.  I am pretty sure it was a short story.  As to how long ago, 1990s or very early 2000s.